What is the meaning of $\delta$ in this formulation of the surface measure with a level set function
I have come across this:

To illustrate the procedure we will use a simple example. If $\Gamma$  is represented by a level set function $\phi$, the area functional $E(\Gamma) = \int_\Gamma 1 d\sigma$ can be written as:
$$E(\phi) = \int_\mathbb{{R}^{m+1}} |\nabla \phi |\delta(\phi) dx$$

The author later refers $|\nabla \phi |\delta(\phi)$ as the surface measure, which I understand to be the area. However, I am confused by the notation, what is $\delta$? It does not appear to be the delta dirac operator.

It's Dirac's delta distribution, but the expression $\delta(\phi)$ should more correctly be written $\delta(\phi(x))$ or $\delta\circ\phi$ if you want it in coordinate-free format.
